# Rebooted EC2 Instance Now WebServer is Down

Tags: amazon-ec2, webserver

So I rebooted an EC2 instance. When I went to pull that website up that links to that instance it is now down with a 521 error saying the website is down. We used Nginx as a web server.

I haven't tried much as I am not familiar with this issue. I do know that I should be trying to restart nginx I just do not know in what directory.

Comment: We believe it may be Gunicorn that is not running. Django runserver works but seems like it needs to be started somehow... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If everything was working fine for you then you can simply bring up the ngnix on ec2 machine using below command :

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Would you input this from root?

Comment: if you are using sudo then it will run as root.

Comment: right. However, when I type that it says nginx.service not found

Comment: when I run it on the instance nothing comes up it just inputs and no feedback

Comment: Can't say much here as it needs to be debugged on the instance level now. You can give a try to this: https://medium.com/@mertcal/install-nginx-on-ec2-instance-in-30-seconds-e714d427b01b

Answer (score 1):

Config file for NGINX was not pointing to the correct website. I guess someone changed the file and me rebooting it enabled the changes. Just went into config file and changed the site back to the one I was using rebooted and bingo.